# Java - Swing - Memory game (Colors)

Tags: java, game, swing

I'm trying to make a first game. I would like to make memory game where you have to find a color matched field.

I made:

MemoryGame - JFrame where I added mainPanel.
In mainPanel I added two another panel becouse both have other layout.
The most of the game code is in ButtonsPanel class. Code in this class work almost like I want.

I don't know how to write the BottomPanel class. I wish to make a restart button which will clear all buttons and will start the game from begining.
I wish to make two JLablel, one of this will show messages like "this field is already matched" etc. and second one will show a number of showed fields.

Can you check this code and give me some comments and leads?

Maybe I should move most of the code from buttomsPanel to MainPanel.

**Card Class:**

```
package memoryGame;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Card extends JButton {

private boolean cardMatched;
private boolean cardSelected;

private String back;


public Card(String back)
{
    this.back = back;
    cardSelected = false;
    cardMatched = false;
}

public String getBack() {
    return back;
}

public void setMatched(boolean matched) {
    cardMatched = matched;
}

public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    cardSelected = selected;
}

public boolean isCMatched() {
    if (cardMatched == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean isCSelected() {
    if (cardSelected == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

**ButtonsPanel Class** - with a most of the game code:

```
package memoryGame;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Random;
import static java.lang.String.valueOf;

public class ButtonsPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

private static final int NUMBER_OF_ROWS = 4;
private static final int NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = 4;
private static final int HORIZONTAL_GAP = 5;
private static final int VERTICAL_GAP = 5;
private static final int PANEL_BORDER = 20;


private Card[][] cards = null;
private String[] colors = {"Blue", "Blue", "Red", "Red", "Green", "Green", "Magenta", "Magenta", "Orange", "Orange", "Cyan", "Cyan", "Black", "Black", "Pink", "Pink"};

private Random random;
private Field field;
private Color color;
private int score = 0;
private Card selectedCard;
private Card c1;
private Card c2;
private Card c3;

public ButtonsPanel(){
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(NUMBER_OF_ROWS, NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS, HORIZONTAL_GAP, VERTICAL_GAP);
    setLayout(layout);

    setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(PANEL_BORDER,PANEL_BORDER,PANEL_BORDER,PANEL_BORDER));

    cards = new Card[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS];
    shuffle();
    setCards();

}
public void setCards() {
    int a = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < cards.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < cards[0].length; column++) {
            cards[row][column] = new Card(colors[a]);
            add(cards[row][column]);
            cards[row][column].addActionListener(this);
            a++;
        }
    }
}

public void shuffle() {
    random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        int pos = random.nextInt(colors.length);
        String temp = colors[i];
        colors[i] = colors[pos];
        colors[pos] = temp;
    }
}

public void setColors(Card card) {
    try {
        field = Class.forName("java.awt.Color").getField(card.getBack().toUpperCase());
        color = (Color) field.get(null);
        card.setBackground(color);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        color = null;
    }
}

public void showCardColor() {
    for (int row = 0; row < cards.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < cards[0].length; column++) {
            if (selectedCard == cards[row][column]) {
                if (!cards[row][column].isCMatched()) {
                    if (!cards[row][column].isCSelected()) {
                        setColors(cards[row][column]);
                        cards[row][column].setSelected(true);
                        mouseClick++;
                        System.out.println(mouseClick);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("This field is already selected");
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("This file is already matched.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


int mouseClick = 0;

public void hideColor() {
    if (mouseClick > 1 && mouseClick % 2 != 0) {
        c1.setBackground(new JButton().getBackground());
        c2.setBackground(new JButton().getBackground());
        c1 = null;
        c2 = null;
    }
}

public void check() {
    if (c1.getBack().equals(c2.getBack())) {
        c1.setMatched(true);
        c2.setMatched(true);
        if (isEndOfGame() == true) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You won in " + score + " moves !");
        }
        c1 = null;
        c2 = null;
        c3 = null;

        c1 = selectedCard;
        showCardColor();

    } else {
        showCardColor();
        c1.setSelected(false);
        c2.setSelected(false);
        hideColor();
        c1 = c3;
        c3 = null;
    }
}

public boolean isEndOfGame() {

    for (Card[] cards2d : cards) {
        for (Card cards1d : cards2d) {
            if (cards1d.isCMatched() == false) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public void doTurn() {
    if (c1 == null && c2 == null) {
        if (!selectedCard.isCMatched()) {
            c1 = selectedCard;
            showCardColor();
        }
    }
    if (c1 != null && c1 != selectedCard && c2 == null) {
        if (!selectedCard.isCMatched()) {
            c2 = selectedCard;
            showCardColor();

        }
    }
    if (c1 != null && c2 != null && c2 != selectedCard && c3 == null) {
        c3 = selectedCard;
        check();
    }
}

Object source;
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    source = e.getSource();                 

    selectedCard = (Card) source;

    doTurn();
    score++;
}
}
```

**BottomPanel Class:**

```
package memoryGame;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class BottomPanel extends JPanel {

private JButton buttonRestart;
private JLabel labelScore;
private JLabel labelMesseges;
private BorderLayout borderLayout;
int score = 0;

public BottomPanel(){

    borderLayout = new BorderLayout();
    setLayout(borderLayout);
    buttonRestart = new JButton("Restart");
    buttonRestart.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,50));
    labelMesseges = new JLabel();
    labelScore = new JLabel("" + labelScore, SwingConstants.CENTER);
    labelScore.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));

    labelMesseges.setText(" ");
    labelMesseges.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0,2,0,2,Color.black));

    labelScore.setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 16));
    labelScore.setText("36");

    add(buttonRestart);
    add(labelMesseges);
    add(labelScore);
    borderLayout.addLayoutComponent(buttonRestart, BorderLayout.WEST);
    borderLayout.addLayoutComponent(labelMesseges,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    borderLayout.addLayoutComponent(labelScore,BorderLayout.EAST);
}
}
```

**MainPanel Class:**

```
package memoryGame;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MainPanel extends JPanel{

private BorderLayout borderLayout;
private BottomPanel bottomPanel;
private ButtonsPanel buttonsPanel;

public MainPanel(){

    borderLayout = new BorderLayout(1,1);

    setLayout(borderLayout);

    buttonsPanel = new ButtonsPanel();
    bottomPanel = new BottomPanel();

    add(buttonsPanel);
    add(bottomPanel);
    borderLayout.addLayoutComponent(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    borderLayout.addLayoutComponent(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
}
```

**MemoryGame Class:**

```
package memoryGame;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MemoryGame extends JFrame {

    private static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 900;
    private static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 900;

    private MainPanel mainPanel;

    public MemoryGame() {

        setSize(new Dimension(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(true);
        setTitle("Memory Game");

         mainPanel = new MainPanel();

        add(mainPanel);

        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Test Class:**

```
package memoryGame;

public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        new MemoryGame();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank for sharing your code.

## Pros

- You actually follow the 
  [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)
- you created a *package*
- you created *constants* for "magic numbers".

## Cons

### - OOP

OOP doesn't mean to "split up" code into random classes.

The ultimate goal of OOP is to reduce code duplication, improve readability and support reuse as well as extending the code.

Doing OOP means that you follow certain principles which are (among others):

- information hiding / encapsulation
- single responsibility
- separation of concerns
- KISS (Keep it simple (and) stupid.)
- DRY (Don't repeat yourself.)
- "Tell! Don't ask."
- Law of demeter ("Don't talk to strangers!")
- replace branching with polymorphism

#### Inheritance

We extend existing classes if we need to chaing the *behavior* of the base class, that is: we *overwrite* one of the base classes methods to do something additional and/or different.

Your classes extend `JPanel` and `JFrame` but do not change their behavior, you just *configure* them which you could also do "from outside"

#### Separations of Concerns / Single Responsibility

Your classes mix *business logic* with *user interaction*. This should always be separated. The best way to do this is to follow the *Model View Controller* Pattern.

### - Coding practices

#### limit scope of variables

in class `ButtonsPanel` you have a variable `source` defined as *member variable* but you only access it inside the method `actionPerformed()`. Therefore it should be defined as *local variable* inside that method.

#### do not have top level class implement `*Listener` interfaces

Swings `*listener` interfaces are meant to be implemented by small *anonymous inner classes*. Do not let you top level classes (the one that defines the file name) this type of interface (unless it is not having any other responsibility).

Comment: Thank you for answer.
I will make a changes in this code, what You sugested.
But if i need one Panel with a gridLayout and second with borderLayout i have to do two separated panels. I still dont know how to do it if i need to change value in bottomPanel, JLabel labelscore every time if someone click a field in buttonsPanel.

Comment: Ok, Thank You Timothy for answer, I'm going to learn more and improve my code.

Answer (score 0):

> But if i need one Panel with a gridLayout and second with borderLayout i have to do two separated panels. I still dont know how to do it if i need to change value in bottomPanel, JLabel labelscore every time if someone click a field in buttonsPanel.

here is a quick and dirty alternative implementation demonstrating:

- configuring Swing components *from the outside* rather than in a child classes constructor,
- use of *anonymous inner classes* (`AbstractAction`)
- separation of different task into methods

Please keep in mind that this example is far from being perfect...

```
package stackexchange.codereview;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ConnectedButtons {

    private static final int APPLICATION_SIZE = 400;
    private static final Color BACKGROUND = new JLabel().getBackground();

    private int score = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ConnectedButtons().runGame();
    }

    private void runGame() {
        JFrame application = new JFrame("color game");
        JLabel scoreLabel = new JLabel("score: "
                + score);
        List<Color> colors = Arrays.asList(Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN, Color.BLACK);
        List<JButton> fieldCells = initializeGame(colors);
        JPanel gameFiled = initializeView(fieldCells);
        bindViewToModel(colors, fieldCells, scoreLabel);
        JPanel gameControl = setupController(colors, fieldCells, application, scoreLabel);
        application.getContentPane().add(gameFiled);
        application.getContentPane().add(gameControl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        application.setSize(APPLICATION_SIZE, 400);
        application.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel setupController(List<Color> colors,
            List<JButton> fieldCells,
            JFrame application,
            JLabel scoreLabel) {
        JPanel gameControl = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        gameControl.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("restart") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                bindViewToModel(colors, fieldCells, scoreLabel);
            }
        }));
        gameControl.add(scoreLabel);
        gameControl.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("quit") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                application.dispose();
            }
        }));
        return gameControl;
    }

    private void bindViewToModel(List<Color> colors, List<JButton> fieldCells, JLabel scoreLabel) {
        Collection<JComponent> clickedButtons = new HashSet<>(); // Model
        Collections.shuffle(fieldCells);
        Iterator<JButton> randomCells = fieldCells.iterator();
        for (Color color : colors) {
            AbstractAction buttonAction = createButonAction(clickedButtons, color, scoreLabel);
            bindButton(buttonAction, randomCells.next());
            bindButton(buttonAction, randomCells.next());
        }
        clickedButtons.clear();
        score = 0;
    }

    private void bindButton(AbstractAction buttonAction, JButton jButton) {
        jButton.setAction(buttonAction);
        jButton.setBackground(BACKGROUND);
    }

    private JPanel initializeView(List<JButton> fieldCells) {
        JPanel gameFiled = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 0));
        for (JButton fieldCell : fieldCells) {
            fieldCell.setBackground(BACKGROUND);
            fieldCell.setEnabled(true);
            gameFiled.add(fieldCell);
        }
        return gameFiled;
    }

    private List<JButton> initializeGame(Collection<Color> colors) {
        List<JButton> fieldCells = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Color color : colors) {
            fieldCells.add(new JButton()); // two buttons per color
            fieldCells.add(new JButton());
        }
        return fieldCells;
    }

    private AbstractAction createButonAction(Collection<JComponent> clickedButtons, Color color, JLabel scoreLabel) {
        AbstractAction buttonAction = new AbstractAction() { // Controller
            Collection<JComponent> clickedPartners = new HashSet<>(); // also Model

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JComponent thisButton = (JComponent) e.getSource();
                clickedPartners.add(thisButton);
                clickedButtons.add(thisButton);
                thisButton.setBackground(color);
                thisButton.setEnabled(false);
                if (2 == clickedButtons.size()) { // is second clicked
                    if (2 == clickedPartners.size()) { // user found partner
                        score += 10;
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(thisButton, "no match");
                        for (JComponent partner : clickedButtons) {
                            partner.setBackground(BACKGROUND);
                            partner.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                        score--;
                    }
                    clickedButtons.clear();
                    clickedPartners.clear();
                    scoreLabel.setText("score: "
                            + score);
                }
            }
        };
        return buttonAction;
    }
}
```